# functional test working in production but not in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm working on a rails website, currently writing some `unit`, `functional` and `integration` tests.

The `unit` and `integration` test are running fine in development(my local machine) and production (on gitlab pipeline).

Strange thing is: `functional test` is failing on my local machine but passing in production pipeline!

I'm using `rake` to run my tests; `rails 4.2` on `macOS` as my local machine setup, and gitlab is using `docker` to run the tests

what might be the issue?

Comment: Post your error stack trace?

Comment: stack trace? code? Any useful information? Have you compared `production.rb` and `test.rb` if there is something that correlates with your test?

Comment: might be due to fixture data.